# Lightest way to set a client screen size validation in node.js before sending web app files?

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, screen-size

I code a web app with node.js and socket.io. I dont want clients with a device screen smaller than 500px*500px to load the game. I want to verify client screen size server side, then send heavy game files or just a little html caution if the device screen isn't large enough. I try to avoid cookies. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the server:

```
socket.emit('screen');
socket.on('size', data => {
   let width = data.width,
       height = data.height;         
   //some code here
});
```

in the client (using jQuery):

```
socket.on('screen', () => {
    let width = $(window).width(),   
        height = $(window).height(); 
    socket.emit('size', {width, height});
});
```

If you don't use jQuery you can send `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` respectively.

You can do easily it at the client side. Have a look at the simple example:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/hello.html');
});
app.get('/small', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/small.html');
});
app.get('/game', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/game.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

hello.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <script>
        if (window.innerWidth < 500 || window.innerHeight < 500) {
            window.location.assign('small');
        } else {
            window.location.assign('game');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

small.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Small screen :-(</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

game.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Loading The Game</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I send a little index.html with this socket.io script in, process on server, then, how do I switch the index.html with the game directory?

Comment: What is your architecture? Do you use express?

Comment: yes! I serve static files like this:                       
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: I think that the simplest way is to do it in the index.html at the client side. Something like: `if (width < 768 && height < 1024) {window.location.assign("smallscreen");} else {window.location.assign("game");}`

Comment: And at the server `app.get("/smallscreen", (req, res) => { res.sendFile("small.html");}); app.get("/game", (req, res) => {res.sendFile("game.html");});`

Comment: is window.location.assign or window.location.replace method can be used to load a folder with app.use server side method ?